# DB2 SQL-Error: -519, SQLState: 24506

Tags: java, tomcat, db2

There is a strut application which throws -519 error sometimes. I would have to restart tomcat whenever this error occures.

You can find te detail of -519 [here](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-519_sqlstate_24506.html)

It rarely happens. But I am not able to understand the actual cause and its solution.

Comment: Are you using connection pools? Can you post the code on which this is failing?

Comment: Yes i am using connection pooling. But sorry, i cant share the piece of code.

Comment: **If you say sorry to share code then we can't do a black magic for you.**

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your code always fetches all results from the ResultSet and make sure ResultSet and PreparedStatement get also always close()d. If you do not ensure these things it is possible that a cursor will not be automatically closed in DB2.

In your case a database connection gets returned back to the connection pool but not all resources have been freed properly. When the eactly same SQL statement is prepared again using the same connection you get the error in question.

If this is custom code of yours I would recommend using PMD and FindBugs extensively while developing because they warn eagerly about not closing all resources.